# No such method/property 'isString' in Firebase Database rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm new in Firebase, I want each project property as string of minimum length 32

```
{
"rules": {
  "project": {
    "$A": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth != null && $A.isString() && 32 <= $A.length",
```

Here `$A` is the project property name `$A.isString()` is not aviliable & getting error

[image]

How i check the `$A` is string of minimum 32 length ?

Comment: ```".write": "auth != null && 32 <= $A.length"``` this worked for me

Comment: `$A` is a key. It's always going to be a string. It's not a ref, so it doesn't have `isString` nor `val` functions, etc.

Comment: @cartant ```".write": "auth != null && 32 <= $A.length"``` this is the currently possible way ? to solve my issue

Comment: Yep, that's the resolution. And the fact that `$A` is a key/string is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Keys are always strings, so you don't need to (and apparently can't even) check for that.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "project": {
      "$A": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null && 32 <= $A.length",
```

By the way: [yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) don't make a difference in Firebase security rules, since we'll never assign a value to the left-hand side of an expression anyway.